# Keyerror in multiple key string interpolation in Python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I am having a problem like

```
In [5]: x = "this string takes two like {one} and {two}"

In [6]: y = x.format(one="one")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-b3c89fbea4d3> in <module>()
----> 1 y = x.format(one="one")

KeyError: 'two'
```

I have a compound string with many keys that gets kept in a config file. For 8 different queries, they all use the same string, except 1 key is a different setting. I need to be able to substitute a key in that file to save the strings for later like:

```
"this string takes two like one and {two}"
```

How do I substitute one key at a time using `format`?

Comment: You can at least do `y = x.format(one="one", two="{two}")` but that may not be the best way to approach it...

Comment: How about `y = x.replace('{one}', 'whatever')` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If placeholders in your string don't have any format specifications, in Python 3 you can use `str.format_map` and provide a mapping, returning the field name for missing fields:

```
class Default(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        return '{' + key + '}'
```

```
In [6]: x = "this string takes two like {one} and {two}"

In [7]: x.format_map(Default(one=1))
Out[7]: 'this string takes two like 1 and {two}'
```

If you do have format specifications, you'll have to subclass `string.Formatter` and override some methods, or switch to a different formatting method, like `string.Template`.

Comment: Pretty interesting approach.

Answer (score 3):

I think [`string.Template`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.Template) does what you want:

```
from string import Template

s = "this string takes two like $one and $two"
s = Template(s).safe_substitute(one=1)
print(s)
# this string takes two like 1 and $two

s = Template(s).safe_substitute(two=2)
print(s)
# this string takes two like 1 and 2
```

Answer (score 2):

you can escape the interpolation of `{two}` by doubling the curly brackets:

```
x = "this string takes two like {one} and {{two}}"
y = x.format(one=1)
z = y.format(two=2)
print(z) # this string takes two like 1 and 2
```

---

a different way to go are [template strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#template-strings):

```
from string import Template

t = Template('this string takes two like $one and $two')
y = t.safe_substitute(one=1)
print(y)  # this string takes two like 1 and $two
z = Template(y).safe_substitute(two=2)
print(z) # this string takes two like 1 and 2
```

([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44576618/4954037) was before mine for the template strings....)

Comment: let's see that one

Comment: for some reason this worked in shell but blew up when I tried to run the server

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `{two}` by `{two}` to enable further replacement later:

```
y = x.format(one="one", two="{two}")
```

This easily extends in multiple replacement passages, but it requires that you give all keys, in each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

All great answers, I will start using this `Template` package soon. Very disappointed in the default behavior here, not understanding why a string template requires passing all the keys each time, if there are 3 keys I can't see a logical reason you can't pass 1 or 2 (but I also don't know how compilers work)

Solved by using `%s` for the items I'm immediately substituting in the config file, and `{key}` for the keys I replace later upon execution of the flask server

```
In [1]: issue = "Python3 string {item} are somewhat defective: %s"

In [2]: preformatted_issue = issue % 'true'

In [3]: preformatted_issue
Out[3]: 'Python3 string {item} are somewhat defective: true'

In [4]: result = preformatted_issue.format(item='templates')

In [5]: result
Out[5]: 'Python3 string templates are somewhat defective: true'
```